# wyswyg html form printing

Tags: html, css, forms, printing, wysiwyg

I am starting this web app project (asp.net mvc)

It's a document-based system, such that nearly each web page is a model of an official printed form (and users sometimes should be able to produce prints).

I am wondering how much cost and time saving it will be if the form could be a wyswyg page that will serve both electronic and paper audiences.

I know that Adobe Acrobat forms has something like that. Would've have been perfect for my purposes but it's not pluggable -- meaning I don't have a choice as to backend system.

Does anyone know anything out there that renders pdf/like pdf to the printer but has html form submit capabilities?

Answer (score 2):

Why not css print media? For example,

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/printstylesheet.css" media="print" />
```

You can define both the things in the same page. Something like this,

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/mainstylesheet.css" media="screen" /> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/printstylesheet.css" media="print" />
```

I hope this is you are looking for, not sure though.

An excerpt from the book [Pro CSS Technique](http://www.digital-web.com/articles/css_styling_for_print_and_other_media/).

**Edited:**

[CSS print media browser conformance](http://www.codestyle.org/css/media/print-BrowserSummary.shtml).

Comment: drawbacks include the standard lack-of-guarantee-on-appearance (which fonts do they have? do CSS image backgrounds get printed? etc)

Comment: Indeed, but there are best-practices to mitigate the possibilities.

Comment: This would be my fall-back position if there are no reusable pieces out there. It sounds like there should be.

Comment: You might want to read this. http://blogs.techrepublic.com.com/programming-and-development/?cat=445

Answer (score 1):

Check out wkhtmltopdf... FOSS and uses webkit rendering engine (safari, google chrome) to convert from html to pdf... I tried compiling it on windows and I got it to work.  Much better than anything else I can find.  Supports all the css I can throw at it.