# Receipt Printing

Tags: html, css, printing

I am trying to make a web app print receipts for my customer (he asked me for it) I've placed a table and everything however when I print it I just can't get it to print correctly into the fields of the receipts. Let me explain, the receipts are already made so I am merely making a place where the user inputs all the required fields and then prints it as if printing a normal web page, being the output paper this receipt (that looks sort of like [this](http://www.monografias.com/trabajos55/documentos-comerciales/Image10677.gif)) anyway I've tried to move where the printer prints using a "print" css but it just won't obey...on top of that the text has gone wayyy small (I really don't know why) and honestly have no idea how to handle this anymore =/...does anyone out there knows?

---

**Edit for Code**

```
* {
    /* old-style reset here :) */
    border: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
table {
    left:0px;
    top:0px;
}
td, th {
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    color: #000;
}

input{
    outline:none;
}

.borde{
    background-color:#0FC;
    border: solid 2px #0FF;

}
```

The HTML is a plain table...with input fields...

Comment: Very difficult to troubleshoot without the code in question.

Answer (score 1):

[This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/580424/wyswyg-html-form-printing/580468#580468) might help. It has some good links related to your problem.

Moreover, how is it showing the preview? Can you share the code?

Answer (score 1):

Unless you've specified somewhere table to have position: absolute, you should add it to the css for the table element. I'm not sure how all browsers handle this, but it should have it anyway.

Answer (score 1):

If you are serving multiple stylesheets, you need to make sure they aren't being applied at the same time. For instance:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" src="default.css" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" src="default.css" media="print" />
```

will apply both stylesheets when printing but only the first in other circumstances.

If you *only* want your print stylesheet to be applied when printing, you need to specify media for all of your stylesheets. Something like:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" src="default.css" media="screen, projection" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" src="default.css" media="print" />
```

and only the print stylesheet will be applied.